# Select using sub-query in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I am new to Pandas and created following example to illustrate a problem I like to solve

***Data***

Consider following dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({ 'Person': ['Adam', 'Adam', 'Cesar', 'Diana', 'Diana', 'Diana', 'Erika', 'Erika'],
                    'Belonging': ['House', 'Car', 'Car', 'House', 'Car', 'Bike', 'House', 'Car'],
                    'Value': [300, 10, 12, 450, 15, 2, 600, 11],
                    })
```

Which looks like this:

```
  Person Belonging  Value
0   Adam     House    300
1   Adam       Car     10
2  Cesar       Car     12
3  Diana     House    450
4  Diana       Car     15
5  Diana      Bike      2
6  Erika     House    600
7  Erika       Car     11
```

***Question***

How to find the Value of Persons Car(s), if they have a House valued more then 400.

The result I am looking for is this:

```
  Person Belonging  Value
4  Diana       Car     15
7  Erika       Car     11
```

How can I achieve this in Pandas, and is there something similar to sub-queries?

*Sub-query*

In SQL there is something called sub-query. Perhaps there is something similar in Pandas.

```
SELECT * 
FROM df 
WHERE person IN 
    (SELECT person 
        FROM df 
        WHERE belonging='House' AND value>400)
AND belonging='Car';

person      belonging   value     
----------  ----------  ----------
Diana       Car         15        
Erika       Car         11
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One approach you can use that is very similar to the SQL statement.

Start by finding the people with houses with value over 400:

```
persons = df.loc[(df['Belonging'] == 'House') & (df['Value'] > 400), 'Person']
```

This will return a series with "Diana" and "Erika".

Then find the cars for such people:

```
df[df['Person'].isin(persons) & (df['Belonging'] == 'Car')]
```

This will return your expected result.

---

Using a join is also possible with [`merge()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html#pandas.DataFrame.merge), which might be more efficient than using `isin()` for a large dataset:

```
df_join = df.merge(persons, on='Person')
```

And then you can filter to find out the car:

```
df_join[df['Belonging'] == 'Car']
```

This will also return your expected result.

---

One different approach to this problem is to pivot the data by turning the belongings into columns, so you'd have a single row per person with all their belongings listed.

You can use [`pivot_table()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot_table.html#pandas.DataFrame.pivot_table) to get this data into a relatively flat dataframe is:

```
df_pivot = df.pivot_table(values='Value', index='Person', columns='Belonging', fill_value=-1)
```

At that point, you can find the value of the cars for people with houses worth more than 400 with:

```
df_pivot.loc[df_pivot['House'] > 400, 'Car']
```

Note that this last one will return a series rather than a dataframe, since Person was now turned into the index. The pivot dataframe method is really useful if you want to gather more information about a person, so having a person in a single row makes it really easy to access all data related to that person.

Comment: I like your solution of using pivot_table(). But requires that no person owns several cars. Let say Diana has two cars valued 15 and 402 respectively. Then the output of Dianas car(s) is 208.5?  The first solution works well!

Comment: @Snowrabbit The `pivot_root()` method takes an `aggfunc` argument, so you can use something like `aggfunc=np.sum` if you prefer to have the sum of values of all cars, or `aggfunc=list` to have a Python list will all car values as the cell value. (Having a Python list can be inconvenient since it's not a native Pandas type.) If you want something more specific, you can probably achieve that through Pandas lower level methods (such as `unstack()`, `drop_index()`, etc.)

Comment: @Snowrabbit That would actually make it an excellent new question! How to get a more interesting result when you have repeated items, that `pivot_table()` can only aggregate, but you'd like something slightly different (specify what you would like instead.)

Answer (score 2):

```
print(df[df.Person.isin(df.loc[df.Value > 400, 'Person']) & (df.Belonging == 'Car')])
```

Prints:

```
  Person Belonging  Value
4  Diana       Car     15
7  Erika       Car     11
```

Answer (score 1):

Consider a set-based (similar to SQL) approach with `merge` and `query` retaining your `WHERE` clauses:

```
final_df = (
            df.query("Belonging == 'Car'")
              .merge(df.query("Belonging == 'House' & Value > 400"), 
                     on="Person", suffixes=["_Car","_House"])
           )

#   Person Belonging_Car  Value_Car Belonging_House  Value_House
# 0  Diana           Car         15           House          450
# 1  Erika           Car         11           House          600
```

Or without the house columns:

```
final_df = (
            df.query("Belonging == 'Car'")
              .merge((df.query("Belonging == 'House' & Value > 400")
                        .reindex(["Person"], axis="columns")), 
                     on="Person")
           )

#   Person Belonging  Value
# 0  Diana       Car     15
# 1  Erika       Car     11
```