# Pandas pivot with multiple items per column, how to avoid aggregating them?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, pivot-table

Follow up to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59989722/9447571), in particular [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59989722/select-using-sub-query-in-pandas/59989971#comment106199717_59989971).

Consider following dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'Person': ['Adam', 'Adam', 'Cesar', 'Diana', 'Diana', 'Diana', 'Erika', 'Erika'],
    'Belonging': ['House', 'Car', 'Car', 'House', 'Car', 'Bike', 'House', 'Car'],
    'Value': [300.0, 10.0, 12.0, 450.0, 15.0, 2.0, 600.0, 11.0],
})
```

Which looks like this:

```
  Person Belonging  Value
0   Adam     House  300.0
1   Adam       Car   10.0
2  Cesar       Car   12.0
3  Diana     House  450.0
4  Diana       Car   15.0
5  Diana      Bike    2.0
6  Erika     House  600.0
7  Erika       Car   11.0
```

Using a `pivot_table()` is a nice way to reshape this data that will allow querying it by Person and see all of their belongings in a single row, making it really easy to answer queries such as "How to find the Value of Persons Car, if they have a House valued more than 400.0?"

A `pivot_table()` can be easily built for this data set with:

```
df_pivot = df.pivot_table(
    values='Value', 
    index='Person', 
    columns='Belonging',
)
```

Which will look like:

```
Belonging   Bike     Car    House
Person
  Adam       NaN    10.0    300.0
 Cesar       NaN    12.0      NaN
 Diana       2.0    15.0    450.0
 Erika       NaN    11.0    600.0
```

But this gets limited when a Person has more than one of the same type of Belonging, for example two Cars, two Houses or two Bikes.

Consider the updated data:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'Person': ['Adam', 'Adam', 'Cesar', 'Diana', 'Diana', 'Diana', 'Erika', 'Erika', 'Diana', 'Adam'],
    'Belonging': ['House', 'Car', 'Car', 'House', 'Car', 'Bike', 'House', 'Car', 'Car', 'House'],
    'Value': [300.0, 10.0, 12.0, 450.0, 15.0, 2.0, 600.0, 11.0, 21.0, 180.0],
})
```

Which looks like:

```
  Person Belonging  Value
0   Adam     House  300.0
1   Adam       Car   10.0
2  Cesar       Car   12.0
3  Diana     House  450.0
4  Diana       Car   15.0
5  Diana      Bike    2.0
6  Erika     House  600.0
7  Erika       Car   11.0
8  Diana       Car   21.0
9   Adam     House  180.0
```

Now that same `pivot_table()` will return the *average* of Diana's two cars, or Adam's two houses:

```
Belonging   Bike     Car    House
Person
  Adam       NaN    10.0    240.0
 Cesar       NaN    12.0      NaN
 Diana       2.0    18.0    450.0
 Erika       NaN    11.0    600.0
```

So we can pass `pivot_table()` an `aggfunc='sum'` or `aggfunc=np.sum` to get the sum rather than the average, which will give us 480.0 and 36.0 and is probably a better representation of the total value a Person owns in Belongings of a certain type. But we're missing details.

We can use `aggfunc=list` which will preserve them:

```
df_pivot = df.pivot_table(
    values='Value', 
    index='Person', 
    columns='Belonging',
    aggfunc=list,
)
```

```
Belonging   Bike           Car           House
Person
  Adam       NaN        [10.0]  [300.0, 180.0]
 Cesar       NaN        [12.0]             NaN
 Diana     [2.0]  [15.0, 21.0]         [450.0]
 Erika       NaN        [11.0]         [600.0]
```

This keeps the detail about multiple Belongings per Person, but on the other hand is quite inconvenient in that it is using Python lists rather than native Pandas types and columns, so it makes some queries such as the total Values in Houses difficult to answer.

Using `aggfunc=np.sum`, we could simply use `pd_pivot['House'].sum()` to get the total of 1530.0. Even questions such as the one above, Cars for Persons with a House worth more than 400.0 are now harder to answer.

What's a better way to reshape this data that will:

- Allow easy querying a Person's Belongings in a single row, like the `pivot_table()` does;
- Preserve the details of Persons who have multiple Belongings of a certain type;
- Use native Pandas columns and data types that make it possible to use Pandas methods for querying and summarizing the data.

I thought of updating the Belonging descriptions to include a counter, such as "House 1", "Car 2", etc. Perhaps sorting so that the most valuable one comes first (to help answer questions such as "has a house worth more than 400.0" looking at "House 1" only.)

Or perhaps using a `pd.MultiIndex` to still be able to access all "House" columns together.

But unsure how to actually reshape the data in such a way.

Or are there better suggestions on how to reshape it (other than adding a count per belonging) that would preserve the features described above? How would you reshape it and how would you answer all these queries I mentioned above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up working out a solution to this one, inspired by the excellent answers by [@SpghttCd](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60056205/9447571) and [@Josmoor98](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60056012/9447571), but with a couple differences:

- Using a MultiIndex, so I have a really easy way to get all Houses or all Cars.
- Sorting values, so looking at the first House or Car can be used to tell who has one worth more than X.

Code for the pivot table:

```
df_pivot = (df
    .assign(BelongingNo=df
        .sort_values(by='Value', ascending=False)
        .groupby(['Person', 'Belonging'])
        .cumcount() + 1
    )
    .pivot_table(
        values='Value', 
        index='Person', 
        columns=['Belonging', 'BelongingNo'],
    )
)
```

Resulting DataFrame:

```
Belonging     Bike     Car           House
BelongingNo    1         1      2        1      2
Person
  Adam         NaN    10.0    NaN    300.0  180.0
 Cesar         NaN    12.0    NaN      NaN    NaN
 Diana         2.0    21.0   15.0    450.0    NaN
 Erika         NaN    11.0    NaN    600.0    NaN
```

Queries are pretty straightforward.

For example, finding the Value of Person's Car**s**, if they have a House valued more than 400.0:

```
df_pivot.loc[
    df_pivot[('House', 1)] > 400.0,
    'Car'
]
```

Result:

```
BelongingNo      1      2
Person
 Diana        21.0   15.0
 Erika        11.0    NaN
```

The average Car price for them:

```
df_pivot.loc[
    df_pivot[('House', 1)] > 400.0,
    'Car'
].stack().mean()
```

Result: 15.6666

Here, using `stack()` is a powerful way to flatten the second level of the MultiIndex, after having used the top-level to select a Belonging column.

Same is useful to get the total Value of all Houses:

```
df_pivot['House'].sum()
```

Results in the expected 1530.0.

Finally, looking at all Belongings of a single Person:

```
df_pivot.loc['Adam'].dropna()
```

Returns the expected two Houses and the one Car, with their respective Values.

Answer (score 1):

Using `groupby`, you could achieve something like this.

```
df_new = df.groupby(['Person', 'Belonging']).agg(('sum', 'count', 'min', 'max'))
```

which would give.

```
                      Value
                        sum  count     min     max
Person  Belonging               
Adam    Car            10.0      1    10.0    10.0
        House         480.0      2   180.0   300.0
Cesar   Car            12.0      1    12.0    12.0
Diana   Bike            2.0      1     2.0     2.0
        Car            36.0      2    15.0    21.0
        House         450.0      1   450.0   450.0
Erika   Car            11.0      1    11.0    11.0
        House         600.0      1   600.0   600.0
```

You could define your own functions in the `.agg` method to provide more suitable descriptions also.

---

### Edit

Alternatively, you could try

```
df['Belonging'] = df["Belonging"] + "_" + df.groupby(['Person','Belonging']).cumcount().add(1).astype(str)

  Person    Belonging   Value
0   Adam      House_1   300.0
1   Adam        Car_1   10.0
2   Cesar       Car_1   12.0
3   Diana     House_1   450.0
4   Diana       Car_1   15.0
5   Diana      Bike_1   2.0
6   Erika     House_1   600.0
7   Erika       Car_1   11.0
8   Diana       Car_2   21.0
9   Adam      House_2   180.0
```

Then you can just use `pivot`

```
df.pivot('Person', 'Belonging')

                Value
Belonging      Bike_1   Car_1   Car_2   House_1   House_2
Person                  
Adam             NaN    10.0      NaN     300.0     180.0
Cesar            NaN    12.0      NaN       NaN       NaN
Diana            2.0    15.0     21.0     450.0       NaN
Erika            NaN    11.0      NaN     600.0       NaN
```

Comment: This summary is definitely useful, but doesn't really make it easy (or even possible?) to answer queries such as "How to find the Value of Persons Car, if they have a House valued more than 400.0?"

Comment: Added a few changes to answer this question. Although I think @SpghttCd has a nice solution

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps sth like this:

given your Pivot table in the following dataframe:

```
pv = df_pivot = df.pivot_table(
    values='Value', 
    index='Person', 
    columns='Belonging',
    aggfunc=list,
)
```

then apply `pd.Series` to all columns.
For proper naming of columns, calculate maximum length of lists in each column and then use 'set_axis' for renaming:

```
new_pv =  pd.DataFrame(index=pv.index)
for col in pv:
    n = int(pv[col].str.len().max())
    new_pv = pd.concat([new_pv, pv[col].apply(pd.Series).set_axis([f'{col}_{i}' for i in range(n)], 1, inplace = False)], 1)


#         Bike_0  Car_0  Car_1  House_0  House_1
# Person                                        
# Adam       NaN   10.0    NaN    300.0    180.0
# Cesar      NaN   12.0    NaN      NaN      NaN
# Diana      2.0   15.0   21.0    450.0      NaN
# Erika      NaN   11.0    NaN    600.0      NaN
```

---

counting of houses:

```
new_pv.filter(like='House').count(1)

# Person
# Adam     2
# Cesar    0
# Diana    1
# Erika    1
# dtype: int64
```

sum of all house's values:

```
new_pv.filter(like='House').sum().sum()

# 1530.0
```

Comment: Yes, this is nice! Though to answer the total value of all houses I'd have to iterate through the columns to figure out how many houses one might have... Such as to find `new_pv.House_0.sum() + new_pv.House_1.sum()` which should yield 1530.0

Comment: or `new_pv.filter(like='House').sum().sum()`

Answer (score 0):

I tried doing this with the lists in the dataframe, so that they get converted to ndarrays.

```
pd_df_pivot = df_pivot.copy(deep=True)
for row in range(0,df_pivot.shape[0]):
    for col in range(0,df_pivot.shape[1]):
        if type(df_pivot.iloc[row,col]) is list:
            pd_df_pivot.iloc[row,col] = np.array(df_pivot.iloc[row,col])
        else:
            pd_df_pivot.iloc[row,col] = df_pivot.iloc[row,col]
```

Comment: Interesting idea! But an easier way to accomplish this is to call `pivot_table()` with `aggfunc=np.array` directly. Having done that, it's possible to get the total value in houses with `df_pivot['House'].apply(np.sum).sum()`. Promising, but I think Pandas columns are still better than ndarrays in cells here.

Comment: I think you would have thought of aggfunc=pd.DataFrame, I am trying to find how you can answer "How to find the Value of Persons Car, if they have a House valued more than 400.0"